# JQuery: How to display DIV based on the selection from a DYNAMIC dropdown list

Tags: jquery

Hello to all and thank you to anyone who can clue me into accomplishing this task. I am attempting to combine two existing fiddles with the goal of displaying individual div content based on a selection that is dynamically created from the first dropdown selection.

e.g., I select "Honda" and the second dropdown populates with all Honda makes, "Honda1". Then display div information based on that selection.

Here's what I'm trying, but I can't seem to get anything to display:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var modelMakeJsonList = {"modelMakeTable" : 
        [
                {"modelMakeID" : "1","modelMake" : "Honda"},
                {"modelMakeID" : "2","modelMake" : "Ford"},
                {"modelMakeID" : "3","modelMake" : "Chevy"},
                {"modelMakeID" : "4","modelMake" : "Nissan"},
                {"modelMakeID" : "5","modelMake" : "Toyota"},
        ]};
var modelTypeJsonList = {"Honda" : 
        [
                {"modelTypeID" : "1","modelType" : "Honda1"},
                {"modelTypeID" : "2","modelType" : "Honda2"},
                {"modelTypeID" : "3","modelType" : "Honda3"},
                {"modelTypeID" : "4","modelType" : "Honda4"},
                {"modelTypeID" : "5","modelType" : "Honda5"},
                {"modelTypeID" : "6","modelType" : "Honda6"}
        ],
        "Ford" : 
        [
                {"modelTypeID" : "1","modelType" : "Ford1"},
                {"modelTypeID" : "2","modelType" : "Ford2"},
                {"modelTypeID" : "3","modelType" : "Ford3"},
                {"modelTypeID" : "4","modelType" : "Ford4"},
                {"modelTypeID" : "5","modelType" : "Ford5"},
                {"modelTypeID" : "6","modelType" : "Ford6"}
        ],
        "Chevy" : 
        [
                {"modelTypeID" : "1","modelType" : "Chevy1"},
                {"modelTypeID" : "2","modelType" : "Chevy2"},
                {"modelTypeID" : "3","modelType" : "Chevy3"},
                {"modelTypeID" : "4","modelType" : "Chevy4"},
                {"modelTypeID" : "5","modelType" : "Chevy5"},
                {"modelTypeID" : "6","modelType" : "Chevy6"}
        ],
                            };
    console.log( "ready!" );
//Now that the doc is fully ready - populate the lists   
//Next comes the make
    var ModelListItems= "";
      for (var i = 0; i < modelMakeJsonList.modelMakeTable.length; i++){
        ModelListItems+= "<option value='" + modelMakeJsonList.modelMakeTable[i].modelMakeID + "'>" + modelMakeJsonList.modelMakeTable[i].modelMake + "</option>";
      }
        $("#makeSelectionBox").html(ModelListItems);
    
    var updateSelectVehicleBox = function(make) {
        console.log('updating with',make);
        var listItems= "";
        for (var i = 0; i < modelTypeJsonList[make].length; i++){
            listItems+= "<option value='" + modelTypeJsonList[make][i].modelTypeID + "'>" + modelTypeJsonList[make][i].modelType + "</option>";
        }
        $("select#modelSelectionBox").html(listItems);
    }
        $("select#makeSelectionBox").on('change',function(){
        var selectedMake = $('#makeSelectionBox option:selected').text();
        updateSelectVehicleBox(selectedMake);
        $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="Honda1"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".Honda1").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="Honda2"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".honda2").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".honda3").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="choose"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".honda4").show();
                }
            });
        }).change();
});
```

```css
.box{
display: none;
}
.Honda1{ background: #ff0000; }
.Honda2{ background: #00ff00; }
.Honda3{ background: #0000ff; }
.Honda4{background: #ffffff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select id="makeSelectionBox" class="stringInfoSpacing">
<option value="-1" selected="selected">Make</option>
</select>
<select id="modelSelectionBox" class="stringInfoSpacing">
<option id="selectVehicleBox" value="-1" selected="selected">Vehicle</option>
</select>
</form>
<div class="Honda1 box">You have selected <strong>Honda1 option</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="Honda2 box">You have selected <strong>Honda2 option</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="Honda3 box">You have selected <strong>Honda3 option</strong> so i am here</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // utility function to show desired vehicle's information 
  function showSelectedVehicleInformation(vehicleID) {
    $("#info > .box").removeClass("show");
    $("#info .box[data-id='" + vehicleID + "']").addClass("show");
  }

  var modelMakeJsonList = {
    "modelMakeTable": [{
        "modelMakeID": "1",
        "modelMake": "Honda"
      },
      {
        "modelMakeID": "2",
        "modelMake": "Ford"
      },
      {
        "modelMakeID": "3",
        "modelMake": "Chevy"
      },
      {
        "modelMakeID": "4",
        "modelMake": "Nissan"
      },
      {
        "modelMakeID": "5",
        "modelMake": "Toyota"
      },
    ]
  };
  var modelTypeJsonList = {
    "Honda": [{
        "modelTypeID": "1",
        "modelType": "Honda1"
      },
      {
        "modelTypeID": "2",
        "modelType": "Honda2"
      },
      {
        "modelTypeID": "3",
        "modelType": "Honda3"
      },
      {
        "modelTypeID": "4",
        "modelType": "Honda4"
      },
      {
        "modelTypeID": "5",
        "modelType": "Honda5"
      },
      {
        "modelTypeID": "6",
        "modelType": "Honda6"
      }
    ],
    "Ford": [{
        "modelTypeID": "1",
        "modelType": "Ford1"
      },
      {
        "modelTypeID": "2",
        "modelType": "Ford2"
      },
      {
        "modelTypeID": "3",
        "modelType": "Ford3"
      },
      {
        "modelTypeID": "4",
        "modelType": "Ford4"
      },
      {
        "modelTypeID": "5",
        "modelType": "Ford5"
      },
      {
        "modelTypeID": "6",
        "modelType": "Ford6"
      }
    ],
    "Chevy": [{
        "modelTypeID": "1",
        "modelType": "Chevy1"
      },
      {
        "modelTypeID": "2",
        "modelType": "Chevy2"
      },
      {
        "modelTypeID": "3",
        "modelType": "Chevy3"
      },
      {
        "modelTypeID": "4",
        "modelType": "Chevy4"
      },
      {
        "modelTypeID": "5",
        "modelType": "Chevy5"
      },
      {
        "modelTypeID": "6",
        "modelType": "Chevy6"
      }
    ],
  };

  console.log("ready!");
  //Now that the doc is fully ready - populate the lists
  //Next comes the make
  var ModelListItems = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < modelMakeJsonList.modelMakeTable.length; i++) {
    ModelListItems += "<option value='" + modelMakeJsonList.modelMakeTable[i].modelMakeID + "'>" + modelMakeJsonList.modelMakeTable[i].modelMake + "</option>";
  }
  $("#makeSelectionBox").html(ModelListItems);

  var updateSelectVehicleBox = function(make) {
    console.log('updating with', make);
    var listItems = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < modelTypeJsonList[make].length; i++) {
      listItems += "<option value='" + modelTypeJsonList[make][i].modelTypeID + "'>" + modelTypeJsonList[make][i].modelType + "</option>";
    }
    $("select#modelSelectionBox").html(listItems);
  }
  $("select#makeSelectionBox").on('change', function() {
    var selectedMake = $('#makeSelectionBox option:selected').text();
    updateSelectVehicleBox(selectedMake);
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
      showSelectedVehicleInformation(this.value);
    });
  }).change();

  $("#modelSelectionBox").on("change", function() {
    showSelectedVehicleInformation(this.value);
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="makeSelectionBox" class="stringInfoSpacing">
  <option value="-1" selected="selected">Make</option>
</select>

<select id="modelSelectionBox" class="stringInfoSpacing">
  <option id="selectVehicleBox" value="-1" selected="selected">Vehicle</option>
</select>

<!-- group your output in a container -->
<div id="info">
  <!-- give a data-id attribute matching selectVehicleBox value  -->
  <div class="box" data-id="1">You have selected <strong>Honda1 option</strong> so i am here</div>
  <div class="box" data-id="2">You have selected <strong>Honda2 option</strong> so i am here</div>
  <div class="box" data-id="3">You have selected <strong>Honda3 option</strong> so i am here</div>
  <!-- ... and so on ...  -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a golden god.